# How to push a cell from an array to another array of controllers?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, uikit

I'm developing a navigation app and also following the chapter 9 in "Beginning iPhone 4 Development". I want my application to be like this:

1. a `rootViewController` contains an array of controllers in `viewDidLoad` part (like the book introduced);
2. after users click on any row of the controllers array, the app will turn to the corresponding screen which also contains an array of controllers;
3. then each row in the array will lead to an image after a click;

That's it. I have completed the coding for `rootViewController` and other controllers in the `viewDidLoad` controller array in `rootViewController.m`, but it just won't go the next controller array.

If anyone knows how to solve this problem, please kindly help me.  Thank You ~~

Comment: It's not clear whether you are following the same code or customizing it. If you are customizing it, can you show the exact code you're using?

Comment: Since when do arrays have rows?

Comment: It's difficult for anyone to answer your question without access to the code from chapter 9 in that book. Is it available online? (provide a link, please) Or can you show us the code you have so far? What do you mean "it just won't go to the next controller array"?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forget to implement tableView Delegate methods. You need to implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath method; when you tap on a cell this method will be called. Then in the method you need to get UIImage Object which you have prefilled in an array through this line of code

```
UIImage* selectedImage = [arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Then allocate your imageViewController and pass the image object to the imageViewController and then push the controller on stack. Hope you understand if not post the code.